# How i can search(or get) sentence by word?

Tags: c#, string, search

I have a word and text. I have to find all the proposals that have the word.
Do you have any idea?

```
piblic List<string> GetSnetences(string word)
{
    // search all proposals that have the word
{
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you post some code?

Comment: I don't have code. I am search any idea

Comment: Please explain better what you want to do, because it's really not clear!!

Comment: Kind of smells like `homework` so please tag it as such if it is an assignment.

Comment: @Yuck - the homework tag [is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception) [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34503/should-the-possible-homework-tag-be-discouraged)

Comment: @Oded: Considered for removal, but not removed. There's still ~12.5k questions tagged for `homework`. IMHO, homework is homework and should be tagged as such. This is clearly not the place for that debate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
var text =
    "Here is some text. It has some sentences. There are a few sentences.";
var word = "SOME";

public List<String> GetSentences(String text, String word) {
    var sentences =
        text.Split(new[] { ". " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var matches = from sentence in sentences
                  where sentence.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower())
                  select sentence;

    return matches.ToList();
}
```

In the end, matches will be an enumeration that has all of the sentences that contain the word you're searching for.

Comment: Your code works and your answer is good; but splitting a text for words is a little harder: think about ?, !, ; and every other possible delimiter ;) Anyway, upvoted

Comment: A sentence is always and only delimited by a period, Mr. Yuck?

Comment: @Marco: Absolutely, the list of delimiters I've used is about as minimal as possible. In practice I'd try to normalize the input text first, or use RegEx.

Comment: I feel that this is a solid starting point. Please post improved answers which I will promptly upvote if they are more complete!

Comment: @Yuck: my comment was not intended to offend you, just to improve your answer. Please forgive me ;)

Comment: @Marco: None taken! My comment was sincere. There's surely a better answer but this does the trick for simple cases and should help get others thinking about more robust solutions.

Comment: @Yuck:How you normalize the input text?

Answer (score 1):

```
piblic List<string> GetSnetences(string word)
{
   string text = "Here is some text. It has some sentences. There are a few sentences.";
   List<string> results = text.Split(".");
   return results.FindAll(delegate(string str) { return str.ToLower() == word.ToLower(); });
}
```

You can try this one.

Answer (score -2):

you can use the contains() method of a string to find out if a string contains some letters o word.

Comment: the method is called Contains. And i think he is looking for a list of results